# How does a triangulation of the punctured plan look like?

Tags: algebraic-topology, triangulation

I know by abstract results that $\mathbb R^2-\{\mathrm{pt}.\}$ has a triangulation. By how can I visualise one?

Comment: Just visualize a bunch of triangles getting smaller and smaller the closer they are to the removed point.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about how the complex exponential sends $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, where values different by $2\pi i$ are sent to the same value.  This means if you take a triangulation of $\mathbb{C}$ that has this vertical symmetry, you can take its image to get a triangulation of $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

Here's the sort of thing you can get:

[image: triangulation of punctured plane]

[image: another triangulation of punctured plane]

Comment: Wow! :) A pretty fancy triangulation! :)  Possibly the questioner should also be informed that there are much simpler (if less aesthetically-pleasing) triangulations, too. :) But I'm not the one to create the relevant graphics. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Possibly I should also be informed about these much simpler triangulations, too!  Do you mean one where you triangulate an annulus with two triangles and nest infinitely many of them? That's how the first one started, but I added the additional 4-fold symmetry to make the triangles clearer.  (By the way, the graphics are just from plotting some circles, lines, and exponential spirals in Mathematica.)